# C++11 standard library features cross compilers support

Tags: c++11, gcc, visual-c++, clang, std

I need to verify that some specific standard library feature is implemented and since which version.

For example: `std::reference_wrapper`

Compilers I need to verify: gcc, clang, msvc

### MSVC

I am able to find https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982605(v=vs.100).aspx so since version 10.0 the reference wrapper is implemented.

### clang

On their webpage http://libcxx.llvm.org/ is written that the library is 100% completed. *Is it possible to find in which version was what implemented?*

### gcc

I found: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support (language support)

Also: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x
- seems reference wrapper is implemented here

But for example 4.8.5 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011
There is:

> This page describes the C++11 support in mainline GCC SVN, not in any particular release.

I'm confused. *Can someone clarify that for me?*

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support is probably going to be your best shot at finding compiler support versions. From there, you'd need to drill down into standard library release notes for specific implementation versions and details.